# PayPal notify url return variables - customer phone number

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to return the buyers phone number in the notify url variables?  I do not see it being returned at all.  I am getting the address and all other profile information but not the phone number?  Is there something I need to set prior or a hidden field I need to setup in the form prior to checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [IPN reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) does list `contact_phone` as an IPN field, my experience is that it is not frequently returned. Many people do not have it in their PayPal account profile (a similar problem exists for Ebay customers). There is nothing you need to do on your end, except make sure you code can process that field. It will be included if it is present.

Comment: In addition to that, you *can* require a phone number to be entered for guest checkout users. This is available via Profile > My selling tools > Payment receiving preferences > Contact phone number > Require a phone number to be entered.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert: I'm not seeing "Payment receiving preferences" in there. Has it moved?

Comment: Try "Website preferences" (quick link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments)