# How can I require a buyer's phone number with Paypal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal

I'm working on Express Checkout integration, and have everything working without any technical problems. The only issue is that we need to have the buyer's phone number.

The [GetExpressCheckoutDetails Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) states that...

> PayPal returns a contact phone number only if your Merchant Account
>   Profile settings require that the buyer enter one.

A comment by PayPal_Robert on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227607/paypal-notify-url-return-variables-customer-phone-number), made in late November of 2013 (So fairly recent) states...

> You can require a phone number to be entered for guest checkout users.
>   This is available via Profile > My selling tools > Payment receiving preferences > Contact > phone number > Require a phone number to be entered.

However, I don't see "Payment receiving preferences" available in my organization's Merchant Profile. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIfFi.png))

Where is the option to require a buyer's contact phone number?

Comment: Try "Website Preferences" (quick link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments).

Comment: @PayPal_Robert Thanks, that's where it was. On another note, [the link itself didn't work](http://i.imgur.com/iKQqWyz.png). Feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: Woops, SO parsed the ) as part of the link. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find this under 'Website Preferences' in your PayPal account's profile.

The direct link to this page is https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments.

Comment: How to add shipping address with ship phonenumber, There is no option

Comment: @YesKaySelva did you ever figure out how to get a phone number for the shipping address?

Answer (score 4):

In Sandbox this will be located here:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website
```

`Selling Tools` > `Update` > Scroll down to contact number and select your preference.
I have created a video walkthrough to demo to do this.
 https://youtu.be/xifEOswaljc

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having trouble getting the phone number: even after I made the prefs change suggested above I couldn't see it in the payment response, but it IS available via a request to /v1/payments/payment/PAYMENT_ID via the REST API. Payer-PayerInfo->Phone.

Comment: Hi dartacus. Can you include the full path of the object (e.g. `$payment->payer->payer_info->phone`) ?

Comment: Hi Jonje, in my code where $json_resp_obj is a StdClass object created from the paypal json response, the phone number can be found at $json_resp_obj->payer['payer_info']['phone']; HTH.