# Collect phone number with PayPal Express checkout

Tags: paypal

I recently added a paypal express checkout to the ecommerce site I work for. So far so good. Unfortunately our courier company like to have a phone number, and this is not included in the data object the express checkout returns.

I have tried the website prefs change outlined here, it made no difference to the checkout or the returned data: [How can I require a buyer's phone number with Paypal Express Checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951993/how-can-i-require-a-buyers-phone-number-with-paypal-express-checkout)

There does not seem to be any documentation on developer.paypal.com that indicates any other change is needed.

Does anybody have any further information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it. You don't get the phone number immediately, but it is available via a request to /v1/payments/payment/PAYMENT_ID via the REST API. Payer-PayerInfo->Phone.