# No returned Phone Number in PayPal API

Tags: laravel, paypal

I checked the data return from paypal using `dd()` in laravel, but there is no phone number listed there. How can I get that data?

I'm using this package: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Screenshot:

[image]

**Update** - *Added required phone in paypal settings*

[image]

**Solution**

Use `$payment->payer->payer_info->phone` to access the phone number.

The `$payment` variable is a `Payment` class like the screenshot above.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got following from PayPal api book page 45.

[image]

Comment: Can I have the link?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951993/how-can-i-require-a-buyers-phone-number-with-paypal-express-checkout and https://books.google.co.in/books?id=RXYuZF-_qiQC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=paypal+api+phone+number&source=bl&ots=M6IzsGw1oB&sig=Ql-L5hBnlzpM-4bEnIQ7E0bd4W0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNgZzb4rXdAhVMvo8KHe6HBk4Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=paypal%20api%20phone%20number&f=false

Answer (score 3):

I cannot guarantee this will be a valid solution, but PayPal says in its Express Checkout documentation that

> Note: PayPal returns a contact phone number only if your Merchant Account Profile settings require that the buyer enter one.

So, start looking into the PayPal account, into your Merchant Profile settings: you should be able to find the option at one of the following the URL

- https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments
- https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website

Someone still have issue on receiving the info and got them by making a subsequent call to `/v1/payments/payment/PAYMENT_ID`.

*(the above answer has been edited to simplify retrieving of all the info present in comments)*

Comment: This is a correct answer, with a small note. Paypal workflows, do not enforce providing a valid phone number for the buyer, so that field may exist or may not, and your application needs to handle both scenarios...

Comment: Can I have a link?  Also, I'm only using developer's account here with the Client and Secret ID.

Comment: Is this the link? https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website

Comment: Hi @SimoneCabrino . I already required it but it is still not showing. Please see my update.

Comment: This URL (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments) brings you to the same page with Phone Required set to ON?

Comment: Thanks for the links ;)

Comment: What is the equivalent for the paypal V2 API